# How to generate URLs dynamically in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a tool (say mytool.com). When a user logs into the tool, I want to use information about the user (like what groups he is part of) to display some links.

For example, user A logs in and I know that user A will be able to to view item "abc" in category 111; so I will display a link on the page which will take the user to that item (something like mytool.com/items/111/abc).

My question is how do I generate these links in JSP. When a user logs in, I call a service to get a list of categories and items he can view (111 and "abc" in this case). How do I correctly translate that into links in JSP?

Additional information:
I want to avoid having Java code in JSP. I am also using Spring mvc. Based on some comments it looks like I should generate the url in the controller and put it in the model and then have the JSP read it. Is that the correct way of going about it?

Comment: Its just basic HTML at that point.

Comment: Just use java code to generate the html code the links. Loop through your dataset and create a link tag for each link you want.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the original question: I want to avoid having Java code in JSP. I am also using Spring mvc. Should I generate the url in the controller and put it in the model and then have the JSP read it?

Comment: Maybe you want to look for URL rewriters.

Comment: @developerwjk it's not just basic HTML at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JSTL to achieve this:

When calling your jsp:

```
  List<Product> products=getProductFromDB();
  request.setAttribute("products", products);//List of products
```

JSP:

```
<table>
 <c:foreach items="${products}" var="product">
     <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/items/${product.category}/${product.name}">${product.name}</a>
         <td>
     </tr>
 </c:foreach>
</table>
```

Spring Controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/items/{category}/{name}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getItem(@PathVariable("category") String category, @PathVariable("name") String name){
     String productname= name;
     String category=category;
     //Do your stuff
  }
```

Incase if you are not familiar with JSTL, take look at [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-with-examples-jstl-core-tags).